# Using subquery for _PARTITIONTIME in bigquery does not limit cost

Tags: google-bigquery, subquery

When I run the below query on BQ using standard SQL, it says it will process 76.6TB when running

```
SELECT 
event_time, user_id, activity_id,dbm_insertion_order_id, dbm_total_media_cost_usd 
FROM `raw.5295.activity_*`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME >(SELECT * FROM `analytics-dwh.autobidding.activity_list` )
AND timestamp_micros(event_time)  > (SELECT timestamp_micros(MAX(event_time)) from `essence-analytics-dwh.ml_for_autobidding.nest_na_4q18_activity_updated_daily`)
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX IN ('25','20')
```

The table analytics-dwh.autobidding.activity_list has just one column with a unique list of integers

If I remove the subquery from the above table, the query uses less than 500GB when run

```
SELECT 
event_time, user_id, activity_id,dbm_insertion_order_id, dbm_total_media_cost_usd 
FROM `raw.5295.activity_*`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME >TIMESTAMP('2018-12-20')
AND timestamp_micros(event_time)  > (SELECT timestamp_micros(MAX(event_time)) from `essence-analytics-dwh.ml_for_autobidding.nest_na_4q18_activity_updated_daily`)
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX IN ('25','20')
```

Why does this happen when I use a subquery? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am doing that now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does this happen with use of subquery?

In general, partition pruning will reduce query cost when the filters can be evaluated at the outset of the query without requiring any subquery evaluations or data scans.

You can see more about [Limiting partitions queried using pseudo columns](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#limiting_partitions_queried_using_pseudo_columns)

So, in your first query (where you use subquery) - the pruning is not happening (It does not limit use of partitions based on the condition that involves the subquery)

In second query you use `_PARTITIONTIME >TIMESTAMP('2018-12-20')` so partitions are limited

Bottom line: filters on _PARTITIONTIME that include subqueries can't be used to limit the number of partitions scanned for a partitioned table.

> Is there a workaround?

You should split your task to two steps: calculate filter for _PARTITIONTIME using whatever logic you need off of table `analytics-dwh.autobidding.activity_list` and then use it (instead of subquery) - using any [client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) of your choice

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks a lot. This was very helpful

Comment: @AksharGupta Was the answer helpful? Mind you keep asking questions and not accepting answers.

Comment: Even though I did not read anything in the official changelog, I observed that under some circumstances, BQ has learned to do "dynamic partition elimination" in mid-2022.

The subquery you use to calculate the timestamp which acts as filter for the partioning column must obviously be a uncorrelated one.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at your query I assume you want to select the MIN or MAX date from this:

```
SELECT * FROM `analytics-dwh.autobidding.activity_list`
```

And pass it to the 2nd part of your query

This can be done by using [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) inside a code which will pass the value between the 2 steps (For example Python or Javascript)

Comment: good point. Sorry for not replying earlier. Thankfully, Mikhail's answer solved the problem but I think what you mentioned here would have helped as well

Answer (score 1):

I noticed by chance that BigQuery is now (since ~ mid 2022) able to do some sort of dynamic partition elimination if some prerequisites are fulfilled.

So let's assume we want to calculate a max timestamp (just like a watermark) from another table and inject it into our filter on the partition column. Tamir Klein suggests to to it in two steps, and that's what the official answer according to the [documentation about partition elimination](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#use_a_constant_filter_expression) is.

However, I found out if

- Your subquery is [uncorrelated](https://www.quora.com/SQL-What-is-the-difference-between-a-correlated-and-an-uncorrelated-subquery)
- Your filter on the main query is on the partition column of the base table (obviously)
- Your base table has at least one level of clustering defined (for whatever reason)

BigQuery is then able to apply dynamic partition elimination and you will only be accounted for the amount of data required to calculate the watermark / subquery plus of course the amount of data that needs to be read from your base table after the parition elimination based on the watermark.

Be aware: The billing cost preview cannot reflect that. At query write/preview time, the BQ optimizer just does not know about which and how many partitions it needs to read because the subquery has not been evaluated yet. You can only see this effect  by looking at the bytes billed metric (which of course is only available AFTER query execution).

For further details, see my [blog entry here](https://medium.com/mediamarktsaturn-tech-blog/kappa-table-architecture-in-bigquery-make-the-most-out-of-your-streaming-data-def74ce410b0).