# SELECT MAX PARTITION TABLE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table with partition on date(transaction_time), And I have a 
problem with a select MAX.
I'm trying to get the row with the highest timestamp if I get more then 1 row in the result on one ID.

Example of data:

```
1. ID = 1 , Transaction_time = "2018-12-10 12:00:00"
2. ID = 1 , Transaction_time = "2018-12-09 12:00:00"
3. ID = 2 , Transaction_time = "2018-12-10 12:00:00"
4. ID = 2 , Transaction_time = "2018-12-09 12:00:00"
```

Result that I want:

```
1. ID = 1 , Transaction_time = "2018-12-10 12:00:00"
2. ID = 2 , Transaction_time = "2018-12-10 12:00:00"
```

This is my query

```
SELECT ID, TRANSACTION_TIME FROM `table1` AS T1
WHERE TRANSACTION_TIME = (SELECT MAX(TRANSACTION_TIME)
                            FROM `table1` AS T2
                           WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID )
```

The error I receive:

> Error: Cannot query over table 'table1' without a filter over
>   column(s) 'TRANSACTION_TIME' that can be used for partition
>   elimination

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/54135893/6253347

Answer (score 0):

It looks like BigQuery does not the correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause.  I don't know how to fix your current approach, but you might be able to just use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.TRANSACTION_TIME
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, TRANSACTION_TIME,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TRANSACTION_TIME DESC) rn
    FROM table1
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: This is correct, See the answer in this thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135893/using-subquery-for-partitiontime-in-bigquery-does-not-limit-cost/54136870#54136870 on how to work partitionTime with subquery

Comment: @TamirKlein Todah rabbah :-)

Answer (score 0):

can be done this way:

```
SELECT id, MAX(transaction_time) FROM `table1` GROUP BY id;
```